# Show that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) / \Gamma (n)$ is isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_n)$.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

$\Gamma (n)= \{ \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})| a,d \equiv 1 \, mod \, n, b,c \equiv 0 \, mod \, n \}$

$\Gamma (n)$ is a normal subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Show that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) / \Gamma (n)$ is isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_n)$.

How can I identify a homomorphism by which these are isomorphic?

My thinking is that since $\Gamma (n) = \begin{pmatrix} Id \end{pmatrix}$ we get that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, which must be isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_n)$. But such a homomorphism can't be bijective, since the second group must be smaller (as the integers run only to $n$).

I suspect it is possible to use the first isomorphism theorem to conclude that they are isomorphic directly? But for that I need a homomorphism for which $\Gamma (n)$ is the kernel.

I can't see how to get on with this. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\Gamma(n)$ is the kernel of the canonical morphism from $SL(2,\Bbb Z)$ onto $SL(2,\Bbb Z_n)$

Comment: It is supposedly obvious that the homomorphism is the reduction $\bmod n$. The difficulty is to prove that it is surjective.

Comment: @AnneBauval That's great, because then I suppose I can use the first isomorphism theorem to get the answer. But what does this canonical morphism look like?

Comment: As reuns wrote: reduction $\bmod n$ (of each of the 4 coefficients of the matrix). The "duplicate" shows it *is* surjective.